# VGA in VHDL using DE0

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm using DE0 FPGA to make a simple game. I'm having problems with the VGA in VHDL. I tried to show on screen a simple rectangle by the VGA, but nothing appear. This is my code. Please help me find the problem.

```
LIBRARY IEEE; 
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
ENTITY vga IS
PORT( 
CLOCK_50:IN std_logic;
VGA_HS,VGA_VS:OUT std_logic;
VGA_R,VGA_G,VGA_B:OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
END vga;
ARCHITECTURE main OF vga IS 
SIGNAL VGCLK :std_logic:='0';
COMPONENT scyn IS 
PORT( 
 clk : IN std_logic;
 Hsync,Vsync:OUT std_logic;
 R,G,B:OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
 END COMPONENT; 

 COMPONENT freq_div1 IS 
PORT ( clkin : IN std_logic ;
       clkout :OUT std_logic ) ; 

END COMPONENT freq_div1  ;
Begin
 freq : freq_div1 port map (CLOCK_50 , VGCLK ) ;
 sync1: scyn      PORT MAP (VGCLK,VGA_HS,VGA_VS,VGA_R,VGA_G,VGA_B);

END main;
```

frequency divider to get 25 MHZ form 50 MHZ of the kit

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;    
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
ENTITY freq_div1 IS 
PORT ( clkin : IN std_logic ;
       clkout :OUT std_logic ) ; 
         END freq_div1  ;

ARCHITECTURE A OF freq_div1 IS 
BEGIN 
PROCESS (clkin )

   variable count  : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) := "00";
begin
if (rising_edge (clkin )) THEN 
          count := count+1 ;
        end if;
        clkout <= count(0) ;
    end process ;
     END A ;
```

640x480 resolution

```
LIBRARY IEEE; 
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE WORK.my.ALL;
ENTITY scyn IS 
PORT( 
 clk : IN std_logic;
 Hsync,Vsync:OUT std_logic;
 R,G,B:OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
 END scyn;
 ARCHITECTURE main OF scyn IS 
 SIGNAL RGB:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
 SIGNAL DRAW :std_logic;
 SIGNAL SQ_X1, SQ_Y1:INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 800:=0;
 SIGNAL Hpos: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 800:=0;
 SIGNAL Vpos: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 525:=0;
 BEGIN
 SQ_X1<= 480;
 SQ_Y1<=285;
PROCESS (clk)
BEGIN 
 IF (clk'EVENT AND  clk ='1') THEN 
 IF (DRAW='1') THEN 
 R<=RGB;
 G<=RGB;
 B<=RGB;
 ELSE 
 R<=(OTHERS =>'0');
 G<=(OTHERS =>'0');
 B<=(OTHERS =>'0');
 IF ( Hpos <800) THEN 
 Hpos<=Hpos+1;
 ELSE
 Hpos<=0;
 IF ( Vpos <525) THEN 
 Vpos<=Vpos+1;
 ELSE
 Vpos<=0;
 END IF; 
 END IF; 
 IF (Hpos >=16 AND Hpos<112) THEN 
 Hsync<='0';
 ELSE 
 Hsync<='1';
 END IF; 

  IF (Vpos>10 AND Hpos<12) THEN 
 Vsync<='0';
 ELSE 
 Vsync<='1';
 END IF; 
 IF ((Hpos>0 AND Hpos<160) OR (Vpos>0 AND Vpos<45)) THEN 
 R<=(OTHERS =>'0');
 G<=(OTHERS =>'0');
 B<=(OTHERS =>'0');
 END IF; 
 END IF; 
 END IF; 
 END PROCESS; 
 END main;
```

to draw the regtangle

```
LIBRARY IEEE; 
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
PACKAGE my IS 
PROCEDURE SQ(SIGNAL Xcur,Ycur,Xpos,Ypos:IN INTEGER; SIGNAL RGB:OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0); SIGNAL DRAW :OUT std_logic);  
END my;
PACKAGE BODY my IS 
PROCEDURE SQ(SIGNAL Xcur,Ycur,Xpos,Ypos:IN INTEGER; SIGNAL RGB :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0); SIGNAL DRAW :OUT std_logic )  IS
BEGIN 
IF (Xcur>Xpos AND Xcur<(Xpos+100)  AND  Ycur>Ypos  AND Ycur <(Ypos+100))
THEN 
RGB <="1111";
DRAW<='1';
ELSE 
DRAW<='0';
END IF; 
END SQ; 
END my;
```

Comment: You could note your horizontal and vertical counters are off by 1 (0 - 799 = 800 clocks per line, 0 -  524 = 525 lines per frame). Compare [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOMRD.png) with a different color and size rectangle against [yours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tIvR.png). Notice the vertical sync looks different. Also vga_r, vga_g and vga_b are always "0000".  Consider simulating your design and troubleshooting.

Comment: Take a look at [ECE448 Lecture 7 VGA Display Part 1](http://ece.gmu.edu/coursewebpages/ECE/ECE448/S13/viewgraphs/ECE448_lecture7_VGA_1.pdf) which I believe leads to a pong game. It shows the numbers H and V counters for porches as well as sample VHDL code

Comment: There can be a number of more reasons that VGA will not work. It could be that you configured your VGA controller incorrectly. (Intel)Altera has specific documentation about using the VGA controller on the DE0 board. [Example](ftp://ftp.altera.com//up/pub/Altera_Material/10.1/Laboratory_Exercises/Computer_Organization/DE0/lab9.pdf). Other site: [EEEWiki](https://eewiki.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15925278). And the code for a VGA color pattern is included as reference design on the Terasic DE0 CD-ROM.

Comment: And please correctly indent your code in your question.

Comment: i saw a video on youtube and i did as he said exactly

Comment: i configured my VGA controller correctly the problem is not there 
but the problem isn't in the H and V counters plz help me to find whre is the problem

Comment: We are willing to help you, but it is very difficult for us this way. 1) I asked you to properly indent your code. It is very difficult to read. 2) We don't have your hardware to test it. So we need a test bench to verify your code. You should write a test bench: it is proper design methodology. 3) Your question does not give sufficient insight. You just show a lot of difficult-to-read code and ask "What is wrong?". Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)